# Error: Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Hi everyone i'm trying to use hooks in my application but it keeps saying
Unhandled Rejection (Invariant Violation): Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component. I'm guessing one of my libraries are conflicting with hooks, since I can't find any problems with the code.

this is my package.json, i'm migrating everything from recompose to hooks... I tried using hooks with nex.js in a test project and it was working fine there...

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "^7.0.2",
    "next-images": "^1.0.1",
    "react": "^16.7.0-alpha.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0-alpha.2",
    "recompose": "^0.30.0",
    "styled-components": "^4.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.9.0",
    "eslint": "^5.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.11.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^0.0.0"
  }
}
```

This is my code:

```
import Layout from "../components/Layout";
import Head from "next/head";
import Register from "../blocks/Register";
import InputBox from "../components/InputBox";
import regexUtils from "../utils/regexUtils";
import { useState } from "react";


function BaseComponent() {
    const { errors, onSubmit } = useOnSubmit();
    const [name, setName] = useHandleInputChange("");
    const [email, setEmail] = useHandleInputChange("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useHandleInputChange("");
    const [passwordAgain, setPasswordAgain] = useHandleInputChange("");

    return (
        <Layout>
            <Head>
                <title>Sheet Builder - Register your account</title>
            </Head>
            <Register>
                <Register.Center>
                    <form>
                        <Register.Box>
                            <Register.Title>Create Account</Register.Title>
                            <InputBox error={errors.name} value={name} onChange={setName}>Your Name</InputBox>
                            <InputBox error={errors.email} value={email} onChange={setEmail}>Email</InputBox>
                            <InputBox error={errors.password} value={password} onChange={setPassword} mask>Password</InputBox>
                            <InputBox error={errors.passwordAgain} value={passwordAgain} onChange={setPasswordAgain} mask hint="Passwords must consist of at least 8 characters.">Password Again</InputBox>
                            <Register.Button onClick={onSubmit} type="submit" value="Register your Sheet Builder account" />
                        </Register.Box>
                    </form>
                </Register.Center>
            </Register>
        </Layout>
    );
}

function useHandleInputChange(initialState) {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(initialState);

    const handleInputChange = (e) => {
        setValue(e.target.value);
    };
    return [value, handleInputChange];
}

function useOnSubmit() {
    const initialState =
    {
        email: false,
        name: false,
        password: false,
        passwordAgain: false
    };

    const [errors, setErrors] = useState(initialState);

    const onSubmit = (e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        let result = {};
        result.email = !regexUtils.isEmailFormatValid(errors.email);
        result.name = !regexUtils.isFormatValid(errors.name);
        result.password = !regexUtils.isPasswordFormatValid(errors.password);
        result.passwordAgain = !regexUtils.isPasswordFormatValid(errors.passwordAgain);
        setErrors(result);
    };

    return {
        errors, 
        onSubmit
    };
}


export default BaseComponent;
```

Comment: What does make a simple function to become a React component? Returning JSX I guess. Your `useHandleInputChange` does not.

Comment: Didn't you forgot to add `import React, {useState} from 'react'` to be able to run your functions as functional components?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a bug with the Microsoft visual studio code debugger. I ran the program from the command line and it worked perfectly afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

you need to import react so that function can be treated as a react functional component

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
```

Read this blog post to understand 
[Why import React from “react” in a functional component?](https://hackernoon.com/why-import-react-from-react-in-a-functional-component-657aed821f7a)